# Realtime audio manipulation

Tags: audio, processing

Here is what i like to achieve:

I like to play around in creating "new" software / hardware instruments.
Sound processing and creation is always managed by software. But one could play the instrument via ultrasonic distance sensor for example. Another idea is to start playback when someone interrupts the light of a photoelectric barrier and so on....

So the instrument would play common sounds, but has to be used in an unusal way. For example, the ultrasonic instrument would play a sound if it detects something in a certain distance. The sound could be manipiulated in pitch for example if the distance gets smaller.

Basically i like to playback a sound sample and manipualte this in realtime.

I guess i have to use WAV samples for this, right? And which programming language do you think fits best for this task?

Edited after kevins hint: please kick me into the right direction - give me a hint where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, now i see downvotes, thats great. It would be even greater if the downvoters would explain their downvotes, so i can learn to ask better questions, which may get an upvote or two... Whats wrong? Bad tags? Help me

Comment: You're being downvoted because this question is too broad for Stack Overflow's format. It's hard for us to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to google. It's much easier to answer specific technical questions such as "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead. What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. After i read my question again i edited it because i thought it does not exactly explain what i like to know. In fact i think i have to edit again.... But the problem here was that i did not know where to start because i was searching with wrong search criterias and therfore i did not find the right answers... The answer of George Profenza is perfect for me, because i now know where i have to start! So if his answer is good, how could the question be too broad? :)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." See also: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are also asking a question that is a matter of opinion rather than fact (eg. ' And which programming language do you think fits best for this task?'). These kind of questions generate flame wars and answers that are not helpful to others.  They are therefore not generally welcome here.

I suggest having a read of the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the the Processing tag, you can try [Processing](http://processing.org/). 
It comes with a sound library like [Minim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) or you can install [beads](http://www.beadsproject.net/) which is great. There's actually a nice book on it: [Sonifying Processing](http://computermusicblog.com/blog/sonifyingprocessing/)

[image: Sonifying Processing book cover]

You might find [SuperColider](http://supercollider.github.io/) fun as well.

The main thing is what are you comfortable with at the moment ?
If Processing syntax looks intimidating, you can actually try a different programming paradigm like data flow. In which case you can use [PureData](http://puredata.info/)(free, opensource) or MaxMSP(very similar, but commercial). The idea is rather than typing instructions, you connect boxes with wires which is fun and the examples are great too.

If you're into c++ there are plenty of libraries. On the creative side, there's a nice set of libraries called [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) that's easy and fun to use. If this is your cup of tea, have a peek at [Maximilian](https://github.com/micknoise/Maximilian).

Bottomline is: there are multiple options to achieve the same task. Choose the best tool for your (based on your background) or try each and see what you like best.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. I just peeked at  beads, which really looks awsome. Im going to check all your suggestions. I was googling and googleing all day long and i never found any of the suggested things here. Thats it, what stackoverflow makes a great place! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You asked "And which programming language do you think fits best for this task?" - I would also suggest using Processing. I have been used Processing to work with sounds previously. And in all cases I used Minim. It has many [UgenS](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/index_ugens.html) to generate sounds programmatically.

Also, you wants to integrate with some sensors. I'm not sure what types of sensors you will use, but Processing goes pretty well with different Arduino modules and sensors. Check this [link](https://processing.org/tutorials/electronics/) for more direction.

Furthermore, you can export your project as .exe or executable .jar files. And their JS version (P5.js) works almost the same as the Java version.